# I used strong law large numbers to solve integral problem, is my answer right?

Tags: proof-verification, law-of-large-numbers

So I am in the beginning of taking probability class. I got this problem from the lecture notes of last year, and I want to try all the problems as much as I can before the new semester starts. I really need you guys to check my answer since noone can do that now.

Problem: By using the strong law of large numbers, with $0<p<q$, compute
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1\int_0^1\dotsi\int_0^1\frac{x_1^q+x_2^q+\dotsb+x_n^q}{x_1^p+x_2^p+\dotsb+x_n^p}\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2\dotsb\mathrm{d}x_n
\end{eqnarray*}
This is my answer: Let $(X_i)$ be a sequence of i.i.d. uniform random variables on unit interval, then the joint probability density function of $X_1,X_2,\dotsc,X_n$ is $f_{X_1,X_2,\dotsc,X_n}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)=1$ on the $n$-dimensional unit cube, and equals to $0$ elsewhere. Hence, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\dotsi\int_0^1\frac{x_1^q+x_2^q+\dotsb+x_n^q}{x_1^p+x_2^p+\dotsb+x_n^p}\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2\dotsb\mathrm{d}x_n&=&E\left(\frac{X_1^q+X_2^q+\dotsb+X_n^q}{X_1^p+X_2^p+\dotsb+X_n^p}\right)\\
&=&E\left(\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^q}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^p}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
By strong law of large numbers, we get for $a>0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^a\xrightarrow{a.s}E(X_1^a)=\frac{1}{a+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Then, the answer of the limit of the integral equals to $\frac{p+1}{q+1}$

Is my answer right? If it is wrong, can you point out where I did wrong? And could you please give me some hints to correct it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Simulposted to MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295543/is-my-answer-about-using-strong-lln-for-calculating-integral-right without notice to either site. PLEASE DON'T.

Comment: For your work on this problem: It looks like you did what you were supposed to do.  One technicality is pushing a limit through an expectation: when is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[Y_n] = E[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Y_n]$?  Do you know any theorems about that, like dominated convergence?  Can you bound the things inside the expectation?  The $0<p<q$ fact may help.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you for telling me, actually that is the first time i used MO, I already deleted there

Comment: @Michael ah i see, that is what i am missing, I got curious why we need the fact $0<p<q$, I understand, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is right, but you need a supplementary argument to justify how the almost sure convergence of $\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^q}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^p}$ implies the convergence of expectations. A dominated convergence argument works here. Indeed, since $ 0\leqslant X_i \leqslant 1$ and $0<p<q$, we have $  X_i ^q\leqslant   X_i ^p$ hence $\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^q}{ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^p}$ is smaller than one and almost surely non-negative (unless $X_i=0$ for all $i$, but the probability of this event is zero).

Comment: thank you so much, yes I realised I missed something, thank you